# Does jQuery not fire hover event on a disabled button?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, button, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing a form, whereby I'm wanting to disable a `button` and show a tooltip explaining why it's disabled on hover. However when a `button` is disabled the tooltip does not show.

I've added a test case here, reproducing with just jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/BYeFJ/1/

It seems that jQuery is not firing the event, or is the browser not firing the hover event?

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap's Tooltip Module](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js) and of course, jQuery.

NB: I've also tried this with a wrapper around the button - but it swallows the hover state it seems, and I've also tried using an `input` element, to the same effect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could put a transparent overlay over the button and put the tooltip on that.

http://jsfiddle.net/yL2wN/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="overlay"></div>                
    <button disabled>BUTTON</button>
</div>
```

---

```
#wrapper{
    position: relative;   
}
#overlay{
    position: absolute;        
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    opacity: .1;
    height: 20px;
    width: 70px;
}​
```

In the fiddle, I set the color to blue just so you can see what's going on.  The width and height of the overlay can be adjusted as needed or made dynamic in js.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to make it ready only:

```
<button id="disabledbutton" readonly="readonly">Disabled Button</button>
```

Then change the css to look disabled and override the onclick to prevent any action:

```
$('#disabledbutton').click(function() { return false; } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow James's guide, I have tried like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
<button id='overlay'>BUTTON</button>
<button disabled>BUTTON</button></div>

#overlay{
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;}
```

I put a fake button with the same text in front of the old and set id to it. In the css, I set the position to let this new button become relative with the wrapper, so that this new button will be placed  in the same space with the disabled button.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p2j041Ln/

Answer (score 1):

Add 'ui-button-disabled' and 'ui-state-disabled' classes so it will look like a disabled button and check for these in the click function to determine the state. Remove them when you need the enabled look.

Answer (score 1):

This could help

```
<style>
 .btn{
   padding: 0 !important; // or get padding size of .btn
 }

 .button{
  padding: 8px 30px 6px;
 }
</style>

<body>
 <button type="submit" id="submit_form" class="btn" disabled/>
  <div class="button">Submit</div>
 </button>

 <script>
  $('.button').hover(function (){
    // place code here
  });
 </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a popup... so I'll share how I did it

```
<span class="d-inline-block" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Some text">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" style="pointer-events: none;" type="button" disabled>Disabled button</button>
</span>
```