# how to display div on mouseover on disabled button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on the requirement that is to perform operations on a disabled button.I want to display a text on a disabled button, i tried in Jquery but its not working, below is the code which i tried.

```js
$(function(){
     $(window).on("load", function () {
     $('#btn').prop("disabled", true);
      
     $("#btn[disabled]").mouseover(function(){
       $(".main").css({ "display": "block" });
       
     })
     $("#btn[disabled]").mouseout(function(){
       $(".main").css({ "display": "none" });
     })
     });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" disabled>Search</button>
     <div class="main" style="display:none">
      this is a div
     </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use the title attribute `title="this is a div"?!

Comment: disabled elements do not fire events. Wrap your button in a div and fire the mouseover event on the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fire onmouseover event when element is disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113937/fire-onmouseover-event-when-element-is-disabled)

Comment: There is a hack solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450641/does-jquery-not-fire-hover-event-on-a-disabled-button

Answer (score 8):

You could do this with CSS instead like below:

```css
#hiddenDiv { display: none; }
#btn[disabled]:hover + #hiddenDiv { display: block; }
```

```html
<button id="btn" disabled>Search</button>
<div class="main" id="hiddenDiv">
    this is a div
</div>
```

What this is doing is initially setting `hiddenDiv` to `display: none;` and then on hover of the `button` it sets it to `display: block;`

Answer (score 2):

Disabling buttons means turning their interactiveness off. While this is a different approach, you may want to achieve desired effect with CSS for browser speed.

```css
button[disabled] + .main {
    display: none;
}

button[disabled]:hover + .main {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" disabled>Search</button>
<div class="main">this is a div</div>
```

Comment: i have done it in javasccript by using title, working mouse over of disbled button document.getElementById("id").title = "some text" i used this syntax in which function i disabled button. the way i did is correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Situation:**

In HTML `disabled` elements don't fire any event and doesn't react to user actions, they are just shown with a grayed-out text.

You can see in the [**disabled** MDN specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled) that :

> If the element is disabled, it does not respond to user actions, it cannot be focused, and the command event will not fire.

**Solution:**

Why don't you simply use the title attribute `title="this is a div"`?!

```
<button id="btn" title="this is a div" disabled>Search</button>
```

Here's a simple Demo snippet:

```html
<button id="btn" title="this is a div" disabled>Search</button>
```